# Stop multiple events firing on JQuery fadeTo

Tags: jquery, events, fadeto

So I want to stop multiple events firing if I hover over a div. This is my code.

```
$( "#menu" ).hover(
  function() {
    $("#menu").fadeTo("slow",0.8);
  },
  function() {      
    $("#menu").fadeTo("slow",0);
   }
);
```

I tried with `stop()` and `stopPropagation()` but didn't succeed, maybe I didn't use them properly.

I want only the first one to execute, and to discard all the events that user might trigger during `fadeTo()` animation. After the animation div should be "hoverable" again.

Comment: What arguments did you provide `stop()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.stop()` jQuery function with `true, false` arguments:

```
$( "#menu" ).hover(
  function() {
     $("#menu").stop(true, false).fadeTo("slow",0.8);
  },
  function() {        
     $("#menu").stop(true, false).fadeTo("slow",0);
  }
);
```

### `.stop( [clearQueue ] [, jumpToEnd ] )`

> Stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements. [[**read more**]](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

So, it will clearQueqe but will **NOT** jump to the end.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nzXVM/)

Comment: @lucafik Thank you too. Some time ago I had the same question, and now I found the answer too. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `stop()` with `true, true`?

```
$("#menu").stop(true, true).fadeTo("slow",0.8);
```